# approximation on a graph

Tags: approximation

I expect my question to sound very naive, please excuse for this. I have a set of $(x, y)$ points on a graph, which are the measurements of a real-life process. Now I want to draw an "approximation line" (or "best-fit line", I don't know what is the right name for it), which should visually show a common tendency of all these measurements. Which technique/method should I use?

ps. I found a way how to do it [manually](http://serc.carleton.edu/mathyouneed/graphing/bestfit.html), but I need an algorithm, in order to render such a line automatically.

Comment: Start with linear regression, go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need something simple and you would be happy getting a linear model, consider a [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) or other similar parametric models. Otherwise, there are many methods, [kernel smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_smoother) would be an interesting one (particularly, a local linear regression is one of my favorites).